# ¿Como ingresar registros a una tabla con llave foranea Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

en mi proyecto los usuarios pueden hacer recargas , tengo a **usuario_id** el cual es la llave foránea en la **tabla recarga** el cual me relaciona la tabla **recargas** con la tabla **usuarios** por lo cual quiero ingresar un nuevo registro en la tabla **recargas** y no se de que manera puedo hacerslo.

en un **select** quiero traer todos los usuarios que tengo en la **tabla usuarios** y después desde ese select guardar el usuario que selecione en la tabla recargas

pero me da este error
**Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (23000)
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'usuario_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `recargas` (`usuario_id`, `cantidad_recarga`, `fecha_recarga`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , 09-02-2019 04:42:55, 2019-02-09 04:42:55, 2019-02-09 04:42:55))
Previous exceptions
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'usuario_id' cannot be null (23000)**

**tabla usuarios**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nombre', 30);
        $table->string('apellidos', 60);
        $table->string('sexo' , 15);
        $table->integer('edad');
        $table->string('correo' , 50)->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**tabla recargas**

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('recargas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('usuario_id')->unsigned();
        $table->decimal('cantidad_recarga' , 8,2);
        $table->dateTime('fecha_recarga');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('usuario_id')->references('id')->on('usuarios');
    });
}
```

**Modelo Usuario**

```
class Usuario extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = ['nombre' , 'apellidos' , 'edad' , 'sexo' , 'correo'];

   public function recargas()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Recarga');
  }
}
```

**Modelo Recarga**

```
class Recarga extends Model
{
   public function usuario()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Usuario');
   }
}
```

**La vista**

```
<br>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('recargas.index') }}"> Ver Usuario  </a>
<form style="width: 400px;border:0px red solid;margin:auto"  method="POST" action="{{ asset('/recargas') }}">
   <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <label for="Nombre">Usuario</label>
       <select name="Usuario" id="Usuario" class="form-control">
         {{-- Aqui Quiero Mostar Los Usurarios --}}
      </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <label for="Cantidad_Recarga">Cantidad De Recarga</label>
       <input type="Cantidad_Recarga" class="form-control" name="Cantidad_Recarga" id="Cantidad_Recarga"  value="" placeholder="Cantidad Recarga">
     </div>
   </div>
   {{csrf_field()}}
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Recargar</button>
 </form>
 <br>
```

**lo que me muestra el navegador**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adicionalmete mostrare un condigo que estaba susando anteriormente y no me funciono , cabe destacar que me esta vista me trae todo los datos que nesesito , pero el momento de guarda me da un error

```
<br>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('recargas.index') }}"> Ver Usuario  </a>
<form style="width: 400px;border:0px red solid;margin:auto"  method="POST" action="{{ asset('/recargas') }}">
   <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <label for="Nombre">Usuario</label>
       <select name="Usuario" id="Usuario" class="form-control">
         @foreach ($usuarios as $usuario)
       <option class="form-control" value="{{ $usuario->usuario_id}}"> {{$usuario->nombre }}</option>
         @endforeach      
      </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <label for="Cantidad_Recarga">Cantidad De Recarga</label>
       <input type="Cantidad_Recarga" class="form-control" name="Cantidad_Recarga" id="Cantidad_Recarga"  value="" placeholder="Cantidad Recarga">
     </div>
   </div>
   {{csrf_field()}}
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Recargar</button>
 </form>
 <br>
```

Comment: Deberías pasar a la vista todos los Usuarios con `compact` o un `array` directamente, e iterar con un `foreach` en la vista.

Comment: `   <tbody>
   @foreach ($usuarios as $usuario)

  @foreach ($usuario->recargas as $recarga)
   <tr>
     <th scope="row"> {{$recarga->id}} </th>
     <td>  {{ $usuario->nombre . " " . $usuario->apellidos}} </td>
     <td> {{$recarga->cantidad_recarga}} </td>
     <td> {{$recarga->fecha_recarga}} </td>
   </tr>
  @endforeach

@endforeach
   </tbody>`

Comment: @Dev. Joel el anterior foreach lo hice para extraer datos tanto de la tablas recargas como de la tabla ususrios y poderlo mostrar en la vista jun , no se si te refieres a algo asi.

Comment: Según lo que entiendo, solo desea mostrar los usuarios en el `select`, la misma lógica usaría, solo que en lugar de construir una table en el `foreach`  crearía option con cada registro ;)

Comment: @Dev. Joel  eso ya lo hice y me muestra correctamente en el **select**  todos los usuarios , el problema esta al momento de guardar no me los guarda , arriba en la pregunta te voy a poner el codigo que use anterior mente y no me guardaba

Comment: Neiider, debes agregar a la pregunta el mensaje de error que te da, la ruta de formulario está mal, quizá deberías tener algo como `{{ route('mirutastore')}}` en el `action` del formulario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de este modo

```
<select  name="user_id" id="">
    @foreach($data as $d)
        <option value="{{$d->id}}">{{ $d->nameUser }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

**OBSERVACIONES**

- La etiqueta `select` va por fuera del `foreach` tanto al inicio como al final
- recorres la variable que trae los datos del usuario
- En el `option` puedes dentro del atributo `value` asignar que agregue como valor el id del usuario
- Por el medio de las etiquetas `option` que abren y cierran puedes mostrar el nombre del usuario
- En el atributo `name` del `select` le puedes asignar por ejemplo el nombre `usuario_id` para poderlo recuperar después en tu controlador y proceder a hacer la inserción de dicho valor

Comment: pero yo en value quiero que sea el valos de **usuario_id** y ahi es que tengo el problema

Comment: es decir en el value quieres que se muestren los id, que se almacenaron como llave foránea en la columna usuario_id? @NeiiderMartinezRivas

Comment: siii , exactamente eso , en el value nesesito los id que se almacenaron como llave foranea , porqe al guardar nesesito que se guarde es el usuario_id , porque si se guardara el el id de la tabla recargas me daria error por llave primaria repetida

Comment: pero se supone que si vas a guardar la recarga que haga un usuario, entonces lo que yo te propongo es correcto, por que el id que se esta cargando en mi ejemplo es del modelo User, entonces cuando hagas el alta ese id lo debes acomodar para mandarlo a la columna que actua como llave foránea, por que finalmente ese valor es el destinado a estar ahi @NeiiderMartinezRivas

Comment: en tu **@foreach($data as $d)** la variable **$data** guarda los valores de la consulta cierto , ahora te pregunto esa consulta la hiciste sobre la tabla usuarios o sobre la tabla recargas , porque no se si lo estoy haciendo mal , pero yo estoy haciendo la consulta sobre la tabla usuarios pero al momento de guardar lo hago sobre la tabla recarga , por eso para el campo usuario_id no tengo ningun valor no se como ponerlo alli.

Comment: asi es como estoy intentando guardar en el controlador de recarga

**public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $recargas = new Recarga();

        $recargas->usuario_id = $request->Usuario;
        $recargas->cantidad_recarga = $request->Cantidad_Recarga;
      

        $recargas->save();
    }**

Comment: si la idea es mostrar un formulario donde lo único dinámico serán los datos del usuario para registrar una recarga, entonces debe ser sobre el modelo Usuario, para que de este modo los datos que cargues en dicho formulario se vayan como registro a la tabla recargas, con lo cual al yo recuperar en el value el id del usuario ya estoy en condiciones de mandarlo para llenar la columna de `usuario_id` que es mi llave foránea @NeiiderMartinezRivas

Comment: ahhh perdóname ya te entendí , la verdad estaba muy clara y sencilla tu explicación pero yo estaba totalmente enfrascado en otra cosa

Comment: para poder registrar el altqa del modo que lo estas haciendo debe ser de este modo `$recargas->usuario_id = $request->input('usuario_id');` donde el usuario_id que esta dentro del input es el name del input de tu select en el html @NeiiderMartinezRivas

Comment: una consulta yo en esta linea **$recargas->usuario_id = $request->input('usuario_id');** no pongo el **input** e igual me funciona , es decir yo pongo **$recargas->usuario_id = $request->usuario_id** es mejor que ponga el **input** o no es nesesario

Comment: una ultima pregunta si te fijastes yo tengo este campo **$table->dateTime('fecha_recarga');** como hago para guardar la fecha y hora actual sin usar un campo **<input type="date">** , porque no quiero que el usuario pueda manipular la fecha y la hora de la recarga sino que la coja del sistema

Comment: puedes colocar un valor tal vez de tipo `NOW()` con ayuda de Carbon, para que de este modo ese valor sea registrado, pero no mandado por el usuario sino que será tomado directamente del sistema por que lo vas a declarar tu, de ese modo se manda ese valor pero el usuario no interviene para declararlo @NeiiderMartinezRivas

Comment: Algo asi cierto 

**$now = new \DateTime();**
**$now->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');**

ya lo probe y si me da la hora , pero ahora como se lo agrego a un campo?

Comment: me parece que esto ya es una pregunta ajena, es decir esta del formulario y el usuario_id me parece ya quedó respondida, entonces para darle buen uso al sitio me parece deberías abrir otra explicando a detalle el tema de la fecha para que igual se te apoye @NeiiderMartinezRivas

Comment: listo , muchas gracias ya la voy hacer